# how to view webpage using Implicit Intent in android

Tags: java, android

EDIT: the complete code now

```
package com.example.shopkart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class netbanking extends Activity {
    datamanager dm;
    String name,mailid;
    String[] productnamearray;
    int[] amount_product,id_array;
    boolean[] checkarray;
    int tablesize,finalbill;
    Spinner spinner_banks;
    WebView wv1;
    Button btnbankselect;

//  @Override
//  public void onBackPressed() {
//      
//  }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.netbanking);
        dm=new datamanager(this);
        wv1=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
        btnbankselect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbankselect);
        spinner_banks=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_banks);
        productnamearray=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("productnamearray");
        checkarray=getIntent().getExtras().getBooleanArray("checkarray");
        id_array=getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("id_array");
        name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        mailid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("mailid");
        finalbill=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("finalbill");
        setspinnervalues();
     btnbankselect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int pos=spinner_banks.getSelectedItemPosition();
            switch (pos) {
            case 0:

                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.loadUrl("http://www.canarabank.in");
//              Intent i1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i1.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
//              startActivity(i1);

                break;
            case 1:

                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.loadUrl("http://www.federalbank.co.in");
//              Intent i2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i2.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
//              startActivity(i2);

                break;
            case 2:

                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.loadUrl("http://www.icicibank.com");
//              Intent i3=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i3.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.icicibank.com"));
//              startActivity(i3);

                break;
            case 3:

                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.loadUrl("http://www.hdfcbank.com"); 
//              Intent i4=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i4.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.hdfcbank.com"));
//              startActivity(i4);

                break;
            case 4:

                wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv1.loadUrl("http://www.onlinesbi.com");
//              Intent i5=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i5.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.onlinesbi.com"));
//              startActivity(i5);

                break;
            }
        }
    });



}
    public void setspinnervalues()
    {
        String[] arrvalues={"Canara Bank","Federal Bank","HDFC bank","ICICI bank","State bank of India"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinner_item,arrvalues);
        spinner_banks.setAdapter(arrap);
    }
}
```

the xml page:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F7F7F7"
    >

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Net banking Page"
        android:textColor="#4B0082"
        android:textSize="65px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose your bank from the below list"
        android:textColor="#4B0082"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
 <Spinner 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_banks" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                 />
 <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="25px"
                android:text="Go to bank"
                android:id="@+id/btnbankselect"
                android:background="#4B0082"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="40px"
                />

 <WebView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="110px"
     android:id="@+id/wv1"
     />
</LinearLayout
```

The browser force closes and the webview doesnt open.help!!
I have removed the spinner event, and the webview loads on a button click, instead of a spinner itemselected event.

Comment: i'm not able to open the webbrowser on each selection of the spinner

Comment: try this way: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.hdfcbank.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I have tried both webview and the above uri method.The browser doesnt open the webpage.

Comment: why? what's matter? did you get any error or any crash? and post your all code for better understanding.

Comment: error:05-01 01:51:09.620: E/chromium(985): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
05-01 01:51:09.620: E/chromium(985): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
05-01 01:51:09.620: E/chromium(985): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
05-01 01:51:09.620: E/chromium(985): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
05-01 01:51:09.620: E/chromium(985): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed

Comment: @user3591768 please add all this info to your question's body

Answer (score 1):

Try code below for browser intent :

```
 //replace your  bank link here
 String link="http://www.bank.com";
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
 startActivity(intent);
```